# How to exit to linux login screen from python code?

Tags: python, shell, login-control

Lets say i login to linux system using admin and password.
How to logout of admin user using python code.?

I tried following:

```
import sys
sys.exit(1)
```

This did not work..

Comment: That's exiting the Python process, as the documentation says...

Comment: Why do you need to do this using Python? Just run `logout` from your shell session

Comment: `os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)  # yolo`

Answer (score 0):

A session leader attached to your terminal must be found. Then send a hangup signal to this process. If it does not work, send a kill signal.

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import time

def runcmd(*args):
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    return cmd.communicate()[0]

tty = runcmd('tty').strip()
for line in runcmd('ps', '-o', 'pid,sess', '-t', tty).split('\n'):
    if line:
        pid, sess = line.split()
        if pid == sess:
            os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGHUP)
            time.sleep(5.0)
            os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```